# "looked to the brass eyelet-holes": why "to" and not "at"? What is the meaning?

Tags: prepositions, idioms, literature

From Thomas Hardy's *[Far From the Madding Crowd](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Far_from_the_Madding_Crowd/Chapter_IV):*

> He thoroughly cleaned his silver watch-chain with whiting, put new lacing straps to his boots, **looked to** the brass eyelet-holes, went to the inmost heart of the plantation for a new walking-stick, and trimmed it vigorously on his way back; took a new handkerchief from the bottom of his clothes-box, put on the light waistcoat patterned all over with sprigs of an elegant flower uniting the beauties of both rose and lily without the defects of either, and used all the hair-oil he possessed upon his usually dry, sandy, and inextricably curly hair, till he had deepened it to a splendidly novel colour, between that of guano and Roman cement, making it stick to his head like mace round a nutmeg, or wet seaweed round a boulder after the ebb.

What is the meaning of the "look to" here? Why is the preposition **to** used? 
Does it mean "he looked at them thoroughly to see if they are clean and shiny"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you looked **to** something in Hardy's day, you tended to it. He presumably cleaned/polished the brass.